# How can I detect whether the current user is on a call?

Tags: windows, windows-10, voip, telephony

I'd like to be able to detect if the user is on a voice/video call, whether it's Skype, Slack, Zoom, Highfive, etc.  I'd like to be able to tap into what Windows itself uses for reducing volume during a call.  I've tried searching a dozen different ways, but can't find any info on this.  There must be a standard event that these various apps are using, but I can't find it (ignoring mobile/phone-specific).  It seems like the answer might lie with [TAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Tapi/telephony-application-programming-interfaces), but how likely is it that these services would all plug into that?

Comment: Your assumption are not correct, the different apps does not to my knowledge have a unified api to tell you the user is in a call.